# Excel logic find the most recent day that is also a day of the work (make logic non-exclusive)

Tags: excel

I am using Excel logic to try and create a seasonal naive forecast.

[image]

I am looking at Column G and then specifying that I only want the rows that are for 9pm, which is the cumulative total sales ending for that day. I am also specifying that I want the maximum date in the file because I only want the total sales for the most recent date. The final condition is that I want the date to be Friday. The problem is, this code only works if I type in "Monday" since the most recent date is also Monday (since the data is updated through end of day yesterday.

How can I make these conditions not-exclusive? I don't want to find the most recent day WHEN it is a Friday, I want to find the most recent Friday, whenever that was.

Here is my attempt so far. It returns the most recent day and a 0 if the most recent day is not Friday. But that's not what I'm looking for, unfortunately.

```
=AVERAGEIFS(All!$G$1:$G$2593,All!$E$1:$E$2593,"9pm" All!$C$1:$C$2593, MAX(All!$C$1:$C$2593),All!$D$1:$D$2593,"Friday")
```

I've also discovered that AVERAGEIFS and SUMIFS does the same thing

```
=SUMIFS(All!$G$1:$G$2593,All!$E$1:$E$2593,"9pm" All!$C$1:$C$2593, MAX(All!$C$1:$C$2593),All!$D$1:$D$2593,"Friday")
```

Comment: Your title specifies DAX, though you haven't used that tag, and you've posted an Excel worksheet formula. Can you clarify?

Comment: Oh I thought that the =if(and(or kind of syntax you use in Excel is always DAX. But I'm seeing I must be wrong about that. I removed the mention about DAX. I'm not looking for a DAX-specific solution, just any solution that works with Excel logic

Comment: Why doesn't `sumifs` work?

Comment: The sumifs is giving me the right answer if the most recent day is Friday, in which case it is working properly. But it is giving me a 0 if the most recent day is any day other than Friday. What I'm really trying to find is the value of the most recent Friday, even if my dataset has the following Saturday, Sunday, and Monday in it. -- and when I get that logic working I would run 7 versions of this formula, one for each day of the week.

Comment: So you are trying to find the last Friday's sale? Maybe `index/match`? Edit: if you are trying to find sales for each weekday, why not just filter 9pm? The last 7 numbers would be it?

Comment: I'm trying to read about index/match now but I'm sort of lost so far how to join it with sumifs. I don't think I can use a filter for this - it's inconsistent how frequently the data is updated, and also probably not the right workflow

Comment: I want to find the value of the the cumm$ column when the date is the most recent date and it's 9pm but only when day = Friday. Would I add a 'when' within sumifs, or can I have a sumifs formula joined by another AND statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a combination of MAXIFS and INDEX/MATCH.

Something like this:

```
=INDEX(All!$G$1:$G$2593,
       MATCH( MAXIFS(All!$F$1:$F$2593,All!$D$1:$D$2593,"Friday"),
       All!$F$1:$F$2593,0)
      )
```

The MAXIFS function wil return the maximum value from the Date_Time column, where the day is "Friday". This will be the latest friday with a timevalue of 21:00. The MATCH function will return the rownumber from this Date_Time value in the Date_Time column. The INDEX function then returns the value with the corresponding rownumber in the Cumm_$ column.